# Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead

Tags: flutter, facebook, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

Hi everyone I am trying to deploy my flutter web app through firebase hosting but getting the following error:

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:flutter_facebook_login_web

If someone can please help me resolve this issue.

Let me know if you require any further information.